# Upgrade failed while upgrading Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Whenever I try to upgrade and update Ubuntu 20.04, the process gets failed.
For example, when I execute a command **sudo apt update** I get **[Waiting for headers]**.
After waiting for long time, terminal shows following message :
**Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9
Connection failed [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx 80]**

Comment: That's a shame. I wonder why? Perhaps you might [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1253341/edit) to provide a bit more description about how you start the process and the results. Please remember that we cannot see what you see, so help us to help you.

Comment: How does it get failed? Does it give an error. Your question tells us next to nothing

Comment: I have updated my question. Kindly help

Comment: This means you have network problems and you can't connect to the update server.

Comment: You can run `ping x.x.x.x` to see if target server responds.

Comment: @Pilot6 My internet is working properly. Still getting same error.